# Failing to install wstools using pip on Mac OS

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install wstools from Mac OS with this command:  pip install wstools

Here's what I receive.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
Downloading/unpacking wstools
  Running setup.py egg_info for package wstools
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/Users/MS/Downloads/build/wstools/setup.py", line 139, in <module>
        tests_require=get_requirements(base_path, 'requirements-dev.txt'),
      File "/Users/MS/Downloads/build/wstools/setup.py", line 129, in get_requirements
        reqs = parse_requirements(req_path, session=False)
    TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Users/MS/Downloads/build/wstools/setup.py", line 139, in <module>

    tests_require=get_requirements(base_path, 'requirements-dev.txt'),

  File "/Users/MS/Downloads/build/wstools/setup.py", line 129, in get_requirements

    reqs = parse_requirements(req_path, session=False)

TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Comment: No issues for me (Py 2.7.10, pip 9.0.1) - what version of `pip` are you running. You could try updating it `pip install -U pip`

Comment: Thank you very much for the update pip idea.  Once I updated pip I was able to install wstools.